# Extracting words from .txt and creating one master .txt

Tags: linux, shell-script

I have multiple files .txt which contain names of people sorted alphabetically so for example in main directory I have directory a which contains one a.txt full with names which start with "a" like "Anna" "Andrew" etc. The same thing repeats in main directory I have directory b containing b.txt full with names etc. up until x,y,z. How can I extract the names and create a master.txt containing all people's names?

Answer (score 2):

You can accomplish this by using the [cat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_(Unix)) command and [filename expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Filename-Expansion.html). If all of these files are in the source directory `/path/to/directory`, and there are no other files in this directory, then the most succinct command would be the following:

```bsh
cat /path/to/directory/*/*.txt > master.txt
```

This will create a file called `master.txt` in your current directory which contains the concatenated contents of all of the files in the source directory. **NOTE:** This will include any files in any of the subdirectories of the source directory.

If there are other files in the directory (or if you just want to be a little bit more precise) then you can use this command instead:

```bsh
cat /path/to/directory/[a-z]/[a-z].txt > master.txt
```

This will only match the following files in the source directory:

```
a/a.txt
a/b.txt
a/c.txt
.
.
.
z/x.txt
z/y.txt
z/z.txt
```

If there are other files in the source directory, or if you have files of the similar to `a/z.txt` where the subdirectory name doesn't match the base-name of the file, and if you want to exclude those files, then you would have to use a more precise command to narrow down the list of matched files. In that case you could use [brace-expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html) and a [for-loop](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Looping-Constructs.html):

```bsh
for letter in {a..z}; do \
    cat "/path/to/directory/${letter}/${letter}.txt"; \
done >> master.txt
```

This will match exactly the files you've specified in your question and no other files.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `main_dir` with the path to your main directory, save this in a script and run from the terminal as `sh ./script-name.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in $( cd main_dir && ls ); do
    cat "main_dir/$i/$i.txt" >> "master.txt"
done
```

Comment: There's no reason to parse the output of `ls` in this situation, since globbing/filename-expansion will work just as well. Also, parsing the output of `ls` is considered bad practice in general. See [Why you shouldn't parse the output of ls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) for more on that topic.